# for loop executes only 1 time

Tags: vhdl

I have a question about using a for loop in an if statement. The if statement is within a process statement. The problem is when I execute this part of the code the for loop is executed but only once regardless of the value of B. I even tried to enter explicit values and ignore B but the loop only executes once. Am I missing something?

The code is part of an ALU behavioral model to apply a logical left shift without using sll.

```
        elsif ALU_Control = "100" then
            -- implement shift logic left by B units 
            if (B > X"00000000") then
                -- Use value of B input as the shift position
                shift_value := TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(B)); 
                -- concatenate a 0 to end of A          
                for index in 0 to shift_value loop
                    temp_A := (A(30 downto 0) & '0');
                end loop;

                ALU_out <= temp_A(31 downto 0) after 100 ps;
            else
                ALU_out <= A after 100 ps; 
            end if;
```

Comment: index is not used in the loop: is it being optmised away?Can you add some logging to prove that temp_A is altered? only once?

Comment: Did you ever end the `elsif` ?

Comment: I'm not sure how. Unfortunately I have just started to learn VHDL. When I run the test bench on Isim (Xilinx) the output for this ALU control input only "shifts" 1 bit no matter what value I use in the index range.

Comment: There is another elsif statement immediately after the end if.

Comment: It seems you are writing VHDL for a HW module (ie not a testbench). So be aware that the `for i to j loop` with either `i` or `j` being not constant (ie no determined statically) may not be supported by your synthesis tool, although it works in simulation. For example Altera Quartus II would reject this.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this part of your code here:

```
for index in 0 to shift_value loop
  temp_A := (A(30 downto 0) & '0');
end loop;
```

That does the same thing every iteration of the loop, so no matter how many times the loop is run, you will get the same result. Perhaps you really meant to have somthing like this:

```
temp_A := A;
for index in 0 to shift_value loop
  temp_A := temp_A(30 downto 0) & '0';
end loop;
```

Answer (score 2):

Without a loop:

```
temp_A := (others => '0');
temp_A(A'high downto shift_value) := A(A'high-shift_value downto A'low);
```